# How can I get motherboard temperature readings in PHP on Debian?

Tags: php

I've got lm-sensors installed, and I am wondering if there are some kind of bindings to access these drivers from within PHP?  I'm wanting to get access to the temperature readings on various servers, and use [pushover](http://www.pushover.net) to notify my iPhone if things get too hot in several remote server rooms.  I also have some [web enabled power switches](http://www.digital-loggers.com/lpc.html) that my servers could access to automatically turn off equipment in an emergency.  I have several other monitoring systems written in batch PHP, so I would rather this be written in PHP, so I can reuse existing code.  Also, it's the language I am most comfortable with.  I guess I could use exec to run sensors and parse the output, but if someone else has already written a PHP class for accessing motherboard temperature readings, I'd like to just use that if possible.

Comment: maybe through stdin://

Comment: If you're running SNMP, PHP has an [implementation for it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.snmp.php), which would solve your concerns about altering output format & multiple sensors. You could also go for a full blown package like cacti or zabbix, define your thresholds, and run a script when those are triggered.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about SNMP, though I probably should.  I have also found that on all of the machines in question, directories like /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0 exist, so maybe I can read them via my PHP scripts.  Can I depend on the correctness of these values?

Comment: Well, my Debian box hasn't got it. It probably _is_ correct, _but_ if you have new machine which doesn't have that file... you'd have to rewrite all sorts of things. If you don't plan to have many server changes this would be OK. I can heartily recommend learning & running snmp, which is a widely used standard of remotely monitoring servers.

Comment: OK, thanks!  If you post the link to the PHP implementation of SNMP, and maybe a link to some kind of tutorial on how to get SNMP set-up and running, I'll accept your answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I wound up going with was using PHP to read the contents of /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp through /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone2/temp.  Those files each contain a single number, that is a temperature in thousandths of a degree.  This is a standard part of the Linux kernel, and [more documentation is available.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt)  This seems to be a standard kernel function, so it should remain available across the majority of newer Linux systems.  It was available on the 6 I tested.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried and tested but you could install a package like `lm-sensors` and then just run the command `sensors` via exec or something similar and print the output

however surely there are better methods of doing this.

**edit**

I was thinking you could log the temp of the cpu or anything in general and just read that log file in php and print the output

Comment: Yes, I could just use exec, as I said in my question.  But that would mean writing code to parse the sensors output, and thus hoping it never changes. Also, my various different machines have different numbers of sensors, with different sensor names, making things slightly more complex.  That's why I was hoping someone had either written php bindings to the lm-sensors library, or a php class to parse this output that I wouldn't have to maintain myself.

Answer (score 0):

i wrote a parser for sensors output,

```
function read_sensors(): array
{
    $raw = shell_exec("sensors -u");
    $things_raw = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n\n", $raw)), 'strlen');
    $things_parsed = array();
    foreach ($things_raw as $thing_raw) {
        $thing = array();
        $lines = explode("\n", $thing_raw);
        $thing['name'] = trim($lines[0]);
        for ($key = 1; $key < count($lines); ++ $key) {
            $line = $lines[$key];
            if (false === strpos($line, ":")) {
                throw new RuntimeException("failed to understand line {$key} (did not contain colon where expected), line content: {$line}");
            }
            $line = trim($line);
            if (substr($line, - 1) === ":") {
                // new category...
                $cat = substr($line, 0, - 1);
                // var_dump("CAT:",$cat,$lines[$key+1],rtrim($lines[$key+1]) !== $lines[$key+1]);
                while ($key < (count($lines) - 1) && ltrim($lines[$key + 1]) !== $lines[$key + 1]) {
                    ++ $key;
                    $curr = trim($lines[$key]);
                    if (false === stripos($curr, ':')) {
                        throw new \RuntimeException("failed to understand line {$key} (did not contain colon where expected #2), line content: {$line}");
                    }
                    $curr = array_map("trim", explode(":", $curr, 2));
                    if (0 === strpos($curr[0], $cat . "_")) {
                        $curr[0] = trim(substr($curr[0], strlen($cat) + 1));
                    } else {
                        // happens on CPU sometimes.. throw new \RuntimeException("expected line {$key} to start with \"{$cat}_\", but it did not! line content: {$lines[$key]}");
                    }
                    $validated_number = filter_var($curr[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
                    if (false === $validated_number) {
                        throw new \RuntimeException("failed to understand line {$key} (expected number, but could not parse as int/float), line content: {$line}");
                    }
                    if (floor($validated_number) === $validated_number) {
                        $validated_number = (int) $validated_number;
                    }
                    $thing[$cat][$curr[0]] = $validated_number; // = $curr[1];
                }
            } else {
                // Adapter: PCI adapter
                $exp = explode(":", $line, 2);
                $exp = array_map("trim", $exp);
                $thing[$exp[0]] = $exp[1];
            }
        }
        $things_parsed[] = $thing;
    }
    return $things_parsed;
}
```

this returns an array looking like:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0d00',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2131,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 70,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0b00',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2147,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 66,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'asus-isa-0000',
    'Adapter' => 'ISA adapter',
    'cpu_fan' => 
    array (
      'fan1_input' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0900',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2151,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 66,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0500',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2098,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 66,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'acpitz-virtual-0',
    'Adapter' => 'Virtual device',
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 27.8,
      'crit' => 119,
    ),
    'temp2' => 
    array (
      'input' => 29.8,
      'crit' => 119,
    ),
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0e00',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2997,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 71,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0c00',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 3007,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 66,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'coretemp-isa-0000',
    'Adapter' => 'ISA adapter',
    'Package id 0' => 
    array (
      'temp1_input' => 60,
      'temp1_max' => 76,
      'temp1_crit' => 92,
      'temp1_crit_alarm' => 0,
    ),
    'Core 0' => 
    array (
      'temp2_input' => 60,
      'temp2_max' => 76,
      'temp2_crit' => 92,
      'temp2_crit_alarm' => 0,
    ),
    'Core 1' => 
    array (
      'temp3_input' => 60,
      'temp3_max' => 76,
      'temp3_crit' => 92,
      'temp3_crit_alarm' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0a00',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 3236,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 64,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0700',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2132,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 65,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'amdgpu-pci-0300',
    'Adapter' => 'PCI adapter',
    'fan1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 2145,
    ),
    'temp1' => 
    array (
      'input' => 63,
      'crit' => 0,
      'crit_hyst' => 0,
    ),
  ),
)
```

on a system where `sensors` return:

```
$ sensors
amdgpu-pci-0d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2165 RPM
temp1:        +71.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0b00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2151 RPM
temp1:        +67.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM

amdgpu-pci-0900
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2163 RPM
temp1:        +67.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2110 RPM
temp1:        +67.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0e00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2997 RPM
temp1:        +72.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        3008 RPM
temp1:        +67.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +61.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 0:        +61.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)
Core 1:        +59.0°C  (high = +76.0°C, crit = +92.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0a00
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        3236 RPM
temp1:        +65.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0700
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2148 RPM
temp1:        +66.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2144 RPM
temp1:        +64.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)
```

and it has been tested on 6 different systems successfully, including debian 9, ubuntu 16.04, ubuntu 18.04, and arch (arch fully updated 2018-01-09), and it failed on a very old amd system (where sensors output format was completely different)